# VBScript - DWORD registery

Tags: vbscript, registry

I want to edit a DWORD in the registry. A normal DWORD value looks like "0x321".

How do I set the registry with this kind of expression?
If I write RegWrite(...,"0x321",...) - it's written as a string.

TY

Answer (score 0):

The last argument (which is optional) of `RegWrite` allows you to specify the type.

You should set this to `"REG_DWORD"` (yes, this is a quoted string) so your supplied string is coerced correctly.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b(v=vs.84).aspx